# Is there attacking from the sea?

Tags: clash-of-clans

In the bottom left corner of your village, in Clash of Clans, there is a sea view with moving waves.

Does this mean Clash of Clans features attacks from the sea, or is this a view, no more, no less?

Comment: Could close voter explain how this question targets unreleased or illegal content?

Comment: @Timelord64 The question is asking if a feature will be released in the future. I think it is anyway- if you want to close as unclear instead, go for it.

Comment: @Studoku, theres nothing unclear about this question, for me. Nor should it be closed as unreleased if we only **think** it has not yet been released. OP is asking if there is anything to the waves, apart from aesthetics, and "not at the moment" appears to be the valid answer.

Comment: I can see how it would be interpreted as requesting future knowledge, however. As such I have edited to specifically ask about present sense. OP has been made aware that future content is off topic, but there is still a question here, since it asks about a game that is already available. If and when an update adds a sea mechanic, the answer can be updated, accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

At present, this is just a nice view for all of us to enjoy. You might be thinking of Boom Beach, another Supercell game, which features attacks from the sea.

Whether this will change, with a future update, nobody can say until release.

Comment: As a side note: The attack can come anywhere on land that is not populated by buildings (plus one square buffer zone). If you have a large wall that leave empty space inside that have no buildings, the enemy can even deploy forces within the walls, and there is no use in your walls if the attacker exploits this!